# Beginner about SQlite relations

Tags: .net, sqlite

Im trying to set up a simple reltion between two tables i SQlite. I´m following a guide that creates this class:

```
 public class Car
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int Milage { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
    }
```

In the guide he creates a repository which creates this table in its `CTOR`

```
 public CarRepository(SQLiteConnection connection)
        {
            _connection = connection;
            _connection.CreateTable<Car>();
        }
```

In my own example I would like to add a second table called `Driver`

```
public class Driver
        {

            public int DriverId { get; set; }
            public string Name{ get; set; }

        }
```

But how can I Set up a relationship if one driver can have many cars? With entity framework I would simply have added:

```
 public virtual ICollection<Car> DriversCars { get; set; }
```

In the `Driver`-class and:

```
public virtual int DriverId { get; set; }
```

in the Car-class.

Is it possible to do this in a similar way in SQlite or do I maybe have to use the Sql-syntax in some way?

Comment: Yes, im creating a windows app.

Comment: Here is the tutorial im using, although im only interested in the windows-part:
http://www.johankarlsson.net/2014/04/setting-up-sqlite-on-ios-android-and.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Entity Framework, it seems there's a way to actually just do that using the `System.Data.SQLite` nuget package - see this other Blob post that seems to do exactly what you want by using that package: [**Entity Framework on SQLite**](http://bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html).